# What is the functionality of Window in Android Graphics?

Tags: android, graphics, window, surfaceflinger

While going throigh the material available online on Android Graphics, I have few queries related to Android Graphics:

1. What is Window ? how it is related to View ?
2. Does every application have its own Window ?
3. Can one application have more than one window ?
4. As Surfaceflinger composes surface does it composes the window also ?

I have gone through other question asked also, but still these question is not clear to me.

Comment: Hey rahul, if you are satisfied with my answer then pls accept this.

Comment: @pekka,animuson...... But I have updated the answer......I have mixed-up the original content with my own answer.......then is it wrong to help the other at SO.